# Redirect in an exported function with react-router-dom without passing anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a very simple logout function that looks like this:

```
export const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('_id')
  localStorage.removeItem('token')
  localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token')

  return {}
}
```

I'd like this function to redirect using `react-router-dom` *but* I'd also like to avoid passing anything to it. This would allow me to call this function outside the scope of a React Component and would mean I don't have to clutter my application by passing the `history` object everywhere. I can't use `redirect` as this function must return an empty object.

In a perfect world I'd be able to import something from `react-router-dom` at the top of the document that would allow me to programatically redirect from within this function.

Answer (score 0):

If you can import the history object in your react component:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const ReactComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  // ... React component to be continued
```

You can pass it into your function:

```
  // ... React component continued
  <button onClick={() => logout(history)}> log out </button>
```

And push a new route to it:

```js
export const logout = (history) => {
  localStorage.removeItem('_id')
  localStorage.removeItem('token')
  localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token')
  
  history.push('/desiredRoute')
  return {}
}
```

Then if you have a `Route` component with its `path` set up as `/desiredRoute` it should render its children.